# Windows 10 is not loading correctly alongside 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS alongside Windows 10 in HP probook 440 G3. I have issues with Windows loader in GRUB, it is not correctly loading. After selecting Windows loader in GRUB, a blank screen is displayed every time and it appears for a long time. Sometimes after shutting down my laptop forcefully, I got Windows running, but this happens 1 out of 10 times.

Now, what should I do to solve this? Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one take a Ubuntu liveCD/USB and open the terminal. Run these lines of code one by one.

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair`

Click recommended repair and do everything it tells you to.